# How to change between 2 classes when a div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, menu

Im trying to add and change the classes of toggle-nav in-between 2 different classes when my other div toggle-btn is clicked  .

I need to have the classes fadeInDown when first clicked and fadeUpOut when the div is clicked again using Jquery

Here is the code I have

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $('.toggle-btn').click( function() {
    $(".toggle-nav").toggleClass("fadeInDown ");

    });
    });


</script>

<div class="container">
<label class="toggle-btn" for="menu-toggle">
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-4x"></i>
<span>MENU</span>
</label>
</div>  

    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"/>

    <div id="toggle-bar" class="toggle-nav animated clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-sections">
                <div class="col-md-4 top-nav-1">item1</div>
                <div class="col-md-3 top-nav-2">item2</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 top-nav-3">item3</div>
                <div class="col-md-3 top-nav-4">item4</div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Any help would be awesome!

Thank you!

-Issac

Answer (score 0):

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu6btnxv/1/). But wouldn't it be easier to add just one class if you want to show the menu (like nav-visible) and make it hidden by default:

```
.toggle-nav {
  height:0;
  transition: 2s height;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#menu-toggle{
  display:none;
}
.toggle-nav.fadeInDown {
  height:100px;
}
```

[See this jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pu6btnxv/3/)

Comment: I see it working on your fiddle but can't seem to get working on my site.

www.tinyurl.com/z32lkxt

Comment: it still just fades out but when that menu button is click it just goes away what i need it to do is make it slide back up using the class fadeOutUp

Comment: you are making multiple mistakes: remove the min-height and max-height on the menu. Also, you are overwriting the transition with `0.3s all` instead of `2s height`. Remove all the CSS you don't need and try again.

Comment: Also, as you are using a checkbox you don't need to add a class with javascript (that's why you are using a checkbox). Just use `#menu-toggle:checked + #toggle-nav` instead of fadeInDown